# How do I get this block of ruby to add each individual hash into an array instead of just adding one hash multiple times?

Tags: ruby, hash

`@session` is formatted as

```
[
  ['time','action','user'],
  ['time','action','user'],
  ...
]
```

and I'm trying to create an array that has those array elements but as hashes of `{:time=>"time, :action=>"action", :user=>"user"}`. The `puts sessions` line outputs each line as I desire, but when I try to capture those hashes into `sessions_array` I receive an array of only one hash repeated many times and not the unique hashes that puts is outputting.

```
sessions = Hash.new
sessions_array = Array.new

@session.each_with_index { |element, index|
  next_element = @session[index+1]

  sessions[:time] = element[0]
  sessions[:action] = element[1]
  sessions[:user] = element[2]

  sessions_array << sessions
  puts sessions
}

puts sessions_array
```

Comment: Can you add example data and the desired output for that data?

Comment: The desired output of the data, in sessions_array, would be [{:time=>"time1", :action=>"action1", :user=>"user1"},{:time=>"time2", :action=>"action2", :user=>"user2"},{:time=>"time3", :action=>"action3", :user=>"user3"},...] . with every hash having unique values.  This output is correctly displayed via the 'puts sessions' command in the block, but the sessions_array only receives one hash repeated and looks like: [{:time=>"time1", :action=>"action1", :user=>"user1"}, {:time=>"time1", :action=>"action1", :user=>"user1"}, {:time=>"time1", :action=>"action1", :user=>"user1"},...]

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `sessions` inside of the `each_with_index` block instead of outside:

```
sessions_array = []

@session.each do |element|
  sessions = {
    time: element[0],
    action: element[1],
    user: element[2],
  }
  sessions_array << sessions
end

puts sessions_array
```

However, this can be done much more succinctly. When you're turning an array into another array with the same number of elements you almost always want to use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-map). Also, in a Ruby block you can extract the elements from an array by specifying multiple names in its arguments (`|foo, bar, ...|`).

This code is equivalent to the above:

```
sessions_array = @session.map do |time, action, user|
  { time: time, action: action, user: user }
end
```

You can see both of these snippets in action on repl.it here: https://repl.it/@jrunning/NavyImmaculateShockwave

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like the following.

**Code**

```
def hashify(data, keys)     
  data.map { |row| keys.zip(row).to_h }
end
```

**Example**

```
data = [
  %w| 11:00 pummel Billy-Bob |,
  %w| 02:00 maim Trixie |,
  %w| 19:00 kill Bill |
]
  #=> [["11:00", "pummel", "Billy-Bob"],
  #    ["02:00", "maim", "Trixie"],
  #    ["19:00", "kill", "Bill"]]

keys = [:time, :action, :user]
```

```
hashify(data, keys)
  #=> [{:time=>"11:00", :action=>"pummel", :user=>"Billy-Bob"},
  #    {:time=>"02:00", :action=>"maim", :user=>"Trixie"},
  #    {:time=>"19:00", :action=>"kill", :user=>"Bill"}]
```

I have chosen to make `data` and `keys` arguments of the method so that those parameters can be modified without affecting the method itself.

Note that each of the three elements of:

```
data.map { |row| keys.zip(row) }
  #=> [[[:time, "11:00"], [:action, "pummel"], [:user, "Billy-Bob"]],
  #    [[:time, "02:00"], [:action, "maim"], [:user, "Trixie"]],
  #    [[:time, "19:00"], [:action, "kill"], [:user, "Bill"]]]
```

is converted to a hash using the method [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h). See also [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-zip).